# Этот код выдает ошибку "return 'outside function Что нужно исправить?

Tags: python

```
graph = {}
graph[ "you"] = [ "alice", "ЬоЬ", "claire"]
graph["bob"] = ["anuj", ]
graph["alice"] = ["peggy"]
graph["claire"] = ["thom", "jonny"]
graph["anuj"] = []
graph["peggy"] = []
graph["thom"] = []
graph["jonny"] = [] 


def person_is_seller(name):
    return name[-1] == 'm'


from collections import deque
search_queue = deque()
search_queue += graph [ "you"]
while search_queue: 
    person = search_queue.popleft()
    if person_is_seller(person):
        print("Да це продавець манго")
        return True
    else:
        search_queue+=graph[person]
return False
```

Comment: return должен использоваться внутри функции. у вас же никакой функции нет.

Comment: Есть чуть выше. В табах потерялся

Answer (score 1):

Удалить два return'а. Оставить только первый.